# Ломается страница при выводе постов в слайдер

Tags: php, html, wordpress, bootstrap

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема:
Есть [сайт](https://xn--l1abga6a.xn----7sbzomjcu.xn--p1ai/) многостраничник. Есть [страница](https://xn--l1abga6a.xn----7sbzomjcu.xn--p1ai/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F/) с постами, где в слайдер сверху выводятся посты. Кусок кода:

```html
<section class="section__1__mer__main" id="back__bg__mer__main">
  <div class="slider__block__mer__main">

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php $carousel_posts = get_posts([
                            'posts_per_page' => 3,
                            'category_name' => 'events',
                            'post_type' => 'post'
                        ]);
                        if (sizeof($carousel_posts) > 0){
                            $count = 0;
                            foreach ($carousel_posts as $post) :
                                setup_postdata($post);?>
        <?php if ($count != 0){
                                    echo '<div class="carousel-item">';
                                }else{
                                    echo '<div class="carousel-item active">';
                                    $count++;
                                } ?>

        <div class="logo__with__text__main__1">
          <div class="text__in__logo__main__1">

            <p href="<?php the_permalink();?>" id="text__in__rectangle__main__1">
              <?php the_title();?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img>
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('main_slider');?>
          </img>
        </a>
      </div>

      <?php endforeach; 
                            } ?>

    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Предыдущий</span>
                    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Следующий</span>
                    </button>
  </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /Первый блок -->
</section>
```

И здесь все работает нормально.
Заказчик попросил на главной [странице](https://xn--l1abga6a.xn----7sbzomjcu.xn--p1ai/) в слайдер выводить те же посты (слайдер пуля в пулю), но при попытке прописать туда вывод постов, ломается страница[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код страницы:

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: О Центре
Template Post Type: page
*/
?>


  <?php get_header(); ?>
  <div class="contant">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="container2">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php $carousel_posts1 = get_posts([
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'category_name' => 'events',
                        'post_type' => 'post'
                        ]);
                        if (sizeof($carousel_posts1) > 0){
                            $count1 = 0;
                            foreach ($carousel_posts1 as $post) :
                                setup_postdata($post);?>
            <?php if ($count1 != 0){
                                    echo '<div class="carousel-item">';
                                    }
                                else{
                                    echo '<div class="carousel-item active">';
                                    $count1++;
                                    } ?>

            <div class="logo__with__text__main__1">
              <div class="text__in__logo__main__1">
                <p href="<?php the_permalink();?>" id="text__in__rectangle__main__1">
                  <?php the_title();?>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
              <img class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail('main_slider');?>
              </img>
            </a>
          </div>
          <?php endforeach; 
                            } ?>

          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Предыдущий</span>
                    </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Следующий</span>
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Первый блок -->
  <!-- Контент 2 -->
  <div class="contant2__main__1">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo(template_url);?>/img/img__container2.png" alt="" /></img>
      <p id="text__in__container2__main__1">
        <?= CFS()->get('main_about_1_txt')?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Конетент 2 -->
  <!-- Контент 3 -->
  <div class="main__contant__back__main__1">
    <div class="contant3__main__1">
      <div class="conteiner">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="col-md-auto">
              <p id="text__contant3__main__1">
                <?= CFS()->get('main_about_2_txt')?>
              </p>
            </div>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo(template_url);?>/img/img__container3.png" id="img__contant__1__main__1" alt="" /></img>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-auto">
            <img src="<?= CFS()->get('main_about_2_img_1')?>" alt="" /></img>
            <img src="<?= CFS()->get('main_about_2_img_2')?>" alt="" /></img>
            <img src="<?= CFS()->get('main_about_2_img_3')?>" alt="" /></img>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- /Контент 3 -->
  <!-- /Контент 4 -->
  <div class="contant4__main__1">
    <div class="container">
      <p id="text__in__container4_1__main__1">В круг основных задач Центра входят:</p>
      <p id="text__in__container4_2__main__1">
        Создание и развитие современной, насыщенной необходимыми кадровыми и техническими ресурсами базы, обеспечивающей непрерывный рост педагога.
      </p>
      <p id="text__in__container4_2__main__1">
        Внедрение инновационных форм и методов повышения профессионального мастерства педагогических работников в образовательный процесс.
      </p>
      <p id="text__in__container4_2__main__1">
        Организация стажировок, предполагающих приобретение педагогических, управленческих компетенций
      </p>
      <p id="text__in__container4_2__main__1">
        Поддержка «горизонтального обучения» в рамках функционирования системы «равный равному», которая активно задействует ресурс профессиональных сообществ педагогов и методических объединений учителей.
      </p>
      <p id="text__in__container4_2__main__1">
        Сопровождение внедряемой региональной целевой модели наставничества.
      </p>
      <p id="text__in__container4_2__main__1">
        Повышение престижа педагогической профессии, в том числе, через развитие конкурсов профессионально мастерства.
      </p>
      <img src="<?php bloginfo(template_url);?>/img/contant4.png" alt="" /></img>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Контент 4 -->
  <!-- Контент 5 -->
  <div class="main__contant__back">
    <div class="contant5__main__1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="text__centr__cont5__main__1">
          <p id="text__contant5__center__main__1">Образовательное пространство</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="sub__contant__5__left__main__1">
            <p id="text__contant__left__main__1">
              <?= CFS()->get('main_obr_space_txt')?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="sub__contant__5__right__main__1">
            <!-- Карусель -->
            <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_1')?>" data-lightbox="photo_2"><img src="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_1')?>" alt="no_image"></a>
            <div class="mini__images__bottom__main__1">
              <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_1')?>" data-lightbox="photo_2"><img src="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_1')?>" alt="no_image" id="mini__img__main__1"></a>
              <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_2')?>" data-lightbox="photo_2"><img src="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_2')?>" alt="no_image" id="mini__img__main__1"></a>
              <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_3')?>" data-lightbox="photo_2"><img src="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_3')?>" alt="no_image" id="mini__img__main__1"></a>
              <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_4')?>" data-lightbox="photo_2"><img src="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_4')?>" alt="no_image" id="mini__img__main__1"></a>
              <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_5')?>" data-lightbox="photo_2"><img src="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_5')?>" alt="no_image" id="mini__img__main__1"></a>
              <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_6')?>" data-lightbox="photo_2"><img src="<?php echo CFS()->get('main_obr_space_img_6')?>" alt="no_image" id="mini__img__main__1"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- /Контент 5 -->

    <!-- Контент 6 -->
    <div class="main__contant__back__blue__main__1">
      <div class="contant6__main__1">
        <div class="conteiner">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
              <!-- Картинка 1 -->
              <div class="img__contant__6__main__1">
                <img src="<?= CFS()->get('main_director_img')?>" alt="" id="img__content__6__left__main__1" /></img>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="class__text__cont__6__main__1">
                <p id="text__contant__6__main__1">
                  <?= CFS()->get('main_director_txt')?>
                </p>
                <p id="fio__contant__6__main__1">
                  <?= CFS()->get('main_director_fio')?>
                </p>
                <p id="doljnost__main__1">
                  <?= CFS()->get('main_director_dojnost')?>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Контент 6 -->
  </div>

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Неделю уже не могу понять в чем проблема. На форумах пишут про mbstring.func_overload, но, насколько я понял, она устарела и не используется в php теперь.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы, надо было в конце цикла с выводом слайдов вставить wp_reset_postdata();
Вот так теперь выглядит полный цикл:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php $carousel_posts1 = get_posts([
                            'posts_per_page' => 3,
                            'category_name' => 'events',
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'suppress_filters' => true
                            ]);
                            if (sizeof($carousel_posts1) > 0){
                                $count1 = 0;
                                foreach ($carousel_posts1 as $post) :
                                    setup_postdata($post);?>
                                    <?php if ($count1 != 0){
                                        echo '<div class="carousel-item">';
                                        }
                                    else{
                                        echo '<div class="carousel-item active">';
                                        $count1++;
                                        } ?>
                                        
                                    <div class="logo__with__text__main__1">
                                        <div class="text__in__logo__main__1">
                                            <p href="<?php the_permalink();?>" id="text__in__rectangle__main__1">
                                                <?php the_title();?>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" >
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('main_slider');?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endforeach; 
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                                } ?>

                        
                        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Предыдущий</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Следующий</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```